# Help with enqueing scripts in footer after init action

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts, wp-register-script

In my functions.php, I have set a register_scripts() and load_scripts(), and hooked them to the 'init' action.

I have registered all the scripts to be loaded in the footer, in order to optimize page load.

Some of the scripts I've registered in register_scripts() are not enqueued in load_scripts() because I only want to load them when / if they are needed.

So for example, if the page being rendered includes the template part 'gallery.php', which needs 'jquery-gallery', I would like to enqueue it from that file, but only after the rest of the footer scripts have been loaded. I also need to do this with inline scripts.

Hope I explained myself well... If not please ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you enqueue the script to the footer while the page is being rendered (after the "wp_head" hook), you will have to manually add wp_print_scripts (or wp_print_footer_scripts) to the wp_footer action, like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-gallery', null, array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
add_action( 'wp_footer', create_function( '', 'wp_print_scripts( "jquery-gallery" );' ) );
```

Comment: This no longer seems to be true. Apparently WordPress now handles scripts enqueued any time before the `wp_footer()` call properly on its own.